# How to get implicit for subclass with link to base class?

Tags: scala, types, shapeless

Example code:

```
trait A
case class B() extends A
case class C() extends A

trait D[T]
implicit object DB extends D[B]
implicit object DC extends D[C]

def getImplicit[T: D](arg: T) = implicitly[D[T]]

val list = Seq(B(), C())
list map getImplicit
```

how can i get implicits without explicitly casting objects in list? maybe i can do it with HList? or perhaps macros can help me?

i tried:

```
case class Wrap[T](v: T)
object getImplicit extends (Wrap ~> D) {
    def apply[T](arg: Wrap[T]) = implicitly[D[T]]
}

val list = Wrap(B()) :: Wrap(C()) :: HNil
list map getImplicit
```

and i get compilation error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter e: D[T]
       def apply[T](arg: Wrap[T]) = implicitly[D[T]]
```

Comment: I suggest removing the scala-macros tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to supply the type class to the apply method of `getImplicit`. Unfortunately that means you'll have to use the long form of `Poly1`:

```
object getImplicit extends Poly1 {
  implicit def default[T: D] = at[Wrap[T]](_ => implicitly[D[T]])
}
```

After this change, your code will compile.